# OAuth2 on iOS app load an uiwebview to let the user accept the connection

Tags: ios, oauth, uiwebview, oauth-2.0, nsurlconnection

OAuth2 on iOS app load an uiwebview to let the user accept the connection(after login with his google account).
I want to load a uiwebview to prompt the user to accept the connection... I must intercept when the user allow the app and than close the webview and get the code returned as parameter in the redirect url.

How can I do?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have written a library to do this (used it in a couple of my own apps). You can find it in github: [LHOAuth2LoginViewController](https://github.com/lari/LHOAuth2LoginViewController)

However, I think my library won't work directly with Google API, since I recall that they don't support `response_type=token`, but instead you have to use `response_type=code`. And also there were some other differences to the [OAuth2 rfc6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749).

But at least you should get the idea for how to intercept the redirection and close the webview. You can check the redirection url in the `-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType` [UIWebViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) method and call `dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^() {}`